# bash aptitude install package list from shell variable

Tags: bash, shell-script, debian, aptitude

I'm on Debian GNU/Linux 8 Jessie, and trying to install packages with aptitude in a bash script from a shell variable. The shell variable is being interpreted as a single package "pkg1 pkg2 pkg3 ... " and is not being found, or only the first package in the list is being parsed.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

set -euo pipefail
IFS=$'\n\t'

# being treated as a single package with spaces in the name
# package "git gist curl build-essential cmake " not found
apt_packages="$(cat packages.txt | grep -Ev '^$|^#' | tr '\n' ' ')"

# only the first package (git) in the list is parsed and installed
apt_packages=( "$(cat packages.txt | grep -Ev '^$|^#')" )

aptitude install "$apt_packages"
```

And the `packages.txt` is what you imagine it would be:

```
git
gist
curl

# build from source
build-essential
cmake
```

Comment: When using the first apt_packages variable, you could try not quoting it, when it's used in the aptitude call. And for the second, if you don't choose an element in the array, or all with [@] it will just use the first I think.

Comment: `aptitude install "${apt_packages[@]}"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After removing the comments from `packages.txt`, what you have is a whitespace-separated list of package names. There is a shell operator to split a string into whitespace-separated parts: unquoted variable or command substitution. Unquoted expansion is actually the “split+glob” operator: it treats the result of the expansion as a list of [glob patterns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_(programming)) which are to be expanded. But since deb package names don't contain any shell wildcard characters, the glob step won't do anything, so you can use the split+glob operator.

Spaces and newlines are both valid separators by default, so you don't need to convert the newlines to spaces. Just keep the default `IFS`. And you don't need to strip blank lines either, as multiple separators are as good as one (when the separators are whitespace).

```
aptitude install $(grep -v '^#' packages.txt)
```